# How can I cancel a single transaction log quickly?

Tags: sql-server, backup, transaction, recovery

First of all I'm trying to disaster scenario for our db. My DB Recovery model is FULL now. And I have full backup. I can do recover from a time point or TransactionID. But I wanna cancel or undo only one TransactionID on SQL Server. How I can do this without third party software? Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI you cannot do `point in time` recovery from full backup.  You will need to have transaction log backup that will cover the time stamp you want to use with `STOPAT`.  For your question do you mean restore to a earlier log sequence number?

Comment: If the transaction has been committed there's no way that you can go back and rollback just that particular transaction.  The best you're going to do is to recover to a point in time before the transaction began.  Depending on what's going on, you might be able to use that as a point of reference to help you undo the change manually.

Comment: I can go back anytime with STOPAT. I can also run the commands of all subsequent operations in succession. This option may be the solution for me. I'm just looking for a faster method. For example, can I parse LOG BACKUP and find and delete the Transaction in it?

Comment: >>>can not I parse LOG BACKUP and find and delete the Transaction in it<<< yes you can parse log backup, but you CANNOT delete smth from it

Comment: You can dig into the transaction logs and there are some 3rd party tools out there that can do it, Toad for one.  Doing it manually isn't an easy thing to do and would likely take you far longer and be far more error prone than just doing a point in time restore and rerunning subsequent transactions in.